# convert DD-MMM-YYYY to DD_MM_YYYY in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a file that contains a date column and the values are `01-Feb-2019 , 01-02-2019 02:00:00`.
I have to convert these into `DD_MM_YYYY` format in spark.
Any suggestions?
I tried below with no luck

```
val r = dfCsvTS02.withColumn("create_dts", date_format($"create_dts", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
```

iS it possible that whatever the way we get the date , it will convert all to `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use functions `to_timestamp` to convert date and `date_format` to format. Something like this:

```
val r = dfCsvTS02.withColumn("create_dts", date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast("date"), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Not getting the expected output.

Comment: val a = Seq(("01-Jul-2019"),("01-Jul-2019 00:01:05"),("Jul-01-2019"),("2019-07-01")).toDF("create_dts").select(col("create_dts"))
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [create_dts: string]

scala>

scala> val r = a.withColumn("create_dts", date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")).show
+-------------------+
|         create_dts|
+-------------------+
|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|01-07-2019 12:00:00|
|               null|
|               null|
+-------------------+

Comment: and If I take 01-07-2019 and 01-Jul-2019, it is only converting the first one not second one

Comment: scala> val a = Seq(("01-Jul-2019"),("01-07-2019")).toDF("create_dts").select(col("create_dts"))
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [create_dts: string]

scala>

scala> val r = a.withColumn("create_dts", date_format(to_timestamp($"create_dts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").cast("timestamp"), "dd-MM-yyyy")).show
+----------+
|create_dts|
+----------+
|01-07-2019|
|      null|
+----------+